# Put in cells on line and not on height

Tags: excel, vba

I have an UserForm with some checkbox. I want when i check this checkbox display on height and not on line.

My code :

```
Private Sub ButtonAdd_Click()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim CTRL As Control
Dim ref As String

If MsgBox("Are you sure ?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation") = vbYes Then

For Each CTRL In Me.Controls
       
       If CTRL.Value = True Then
        
            LastRow = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ref = Split(CTRL.Name, "Chk")(1)
            Range("A" & LastRow).Value = CTRL.Caption
        End If
    
Next CTRL
End If
```

Comment: Your question title says "on line and not on height", while in the question you say "on line and not on row". Which is it. I`m not sure what you mean either way. Maybe a screencap of the expected result would be useful?

Comment: `Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0,1).value = CTRL.Caption` for example

Comment: Yeah sorry it's modified @cybernetic.nomad